# Difference between iOS app with Watch App vs Watch App

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos

I am trying to make a Watch App that tracks user motion activities. This data will be sent to the iOS app, processed, and then sent to a server. However, if the iOS phone is not present, the Watch App will need to be able to temporarily hold the data until it's able to transfer it to the phone.

From what I read in the [Apple article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/creating_independent_watchos_apps), if you are making an "iOS App with Watch App" it will either be independent or dependent. Is this a correct summary of the types of projects?

Choose "Watch App" if:

1. Your watch app does not need an iOS companion

Choose "iOS with Watch App" if:

1. Your watch app may need or may not need an iOS companion

If that's the case, would my project fall under the "iOS with Watch App" + dependent type?

Can a "Watch App" only project still interact with an iOS app via Bluetooth?

**Why pick "Watch App" only, if you can make a "iOS with Watch App" project but make the watch app independent?**

Comment: that's quite obvious. You need the iOS app. Therefore you have to choose "iOS with Watch App", otherwise your Watch App cannot communicate with the iOS app.

Comment: @Raptor Oh I see, I did not know that the Watch App would not be able to communicate with an iOS app. Thanks for the answer